# How to get column value at Htmlservice table of an loop with onclick=google.script.run.taxBill(this.value)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-table, spreadsheet

I have two google apps scripts which are the both of them can do some stuff with connected each others. First script the ***selectCheckBillName*** shows the Popup with the Htmlservice of the table of an loop and have call the another one function after it has selected the name of the list on it. It is "***taxBill**(**this.value**)*". The script which's the "taxBill" is the second function as a handle of main all of the script to handling the function of main all the purpose of the script where it's showing the data result after selected their name and it must be shown supposed be, here's the code of the ***selectCheckBillName***:

```
function selectCheckBillName() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var val = ss.getRange("B:B").getValues();
  var result = "<head><script type='text/javascript'>function highlight(e) {var table = e.parentNode.parentNode, trs = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'); for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {trs[i].style.backgroundColor = null; trs[i].style.color = null; } e.style.backgroundColor = '#e68a00'; e.style.color = 'white';}</script><style type='text/css'>.gridview {display:inline-block; border-collapse:collapse; margin:0px 4px 4px 0; box-shadow:3px 3px 4px #bbb;} .gridview, .gridview td, .gridview th {margin:0; border:1px solid #cccccc; width:200px;} .gridview th {font-size:1.1em; height:25px; text-align:center; font-weight:normal; color:#F9F9F9; background:#337EB5;} .gridview tr {background:#F4F9FD;} .gridview tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#ffffcc;} .gridview tr:nth-child(even) {background-color:#ffffe6;} .gridview td {font-weight:normal; text-align:left; vertical-align:top; padding:4px 9px 5px 9px;} .gridview tfoot td {background-color:#EEEEEE;} .gridview tfoot td .page {color:#000000; font-weight:bold;} .gridview tr.subfoot, .gridview tr.subfoot td {background-color:#FFFFEC;} .gridview tr:hover td, .gridview tbody tr:hover td {background-color:#ffc266; cursor:pointer; color:white;}}</style></head><table border=1 class='gridview'>";
    for (var i=1, iLen=val.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        result += "<tr OnClick=highlight(this)>";
          result += "<td OnClick=google.script.run.taxBill(this.value) value="+val[i]+">"+val[i]+"</td>";
      result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";

  ss.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(result)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle("T a x    R e k e n i n g")
    .setHeight(500)
    .setWidth(235));
}
```

This is the ***taxBill*** function :

```
function taxBill(val) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var destSheet = s.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vals = destSheet.getRange(1, 2, destSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--)
      if (vals[i][0] == val) break;
      var TotalSmw = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 16).getValue();
      var TotalLstk = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 14).getValue();
      var HargaLstk = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 13).getValue();
      var pmkaianLstk = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 12).getValue();
      var MtrnAwalLstk = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 11).getValue();
      var MtrnAkhrLstk = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 10).getValue();
      var TotalAir = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 8).getValue();
      var HargaAir = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 7).getValue();
      var pmkaianAir = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 6).getValue();
      var MtrnAwalAir = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 5).getValue();
      var MtrnAkhrAir = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 4).getValue();
      var admin = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 46).getValue();
      var client = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 18).getValue();
      var checkInDate = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 17).getValue();
      var checkUpDate = destSheet.getRange(i+1, 3).getValue();
      var subject = "Perincian Data & Informasi";
      var unitRp = "Rp.    ";
      var unitKw = "  kwh";
      var unitM = "  m³";
      var NB = "INFORMASI   REKENING   TERAKHIR    ATAS    NAMA        " + val + "         ❗❗❗";
  var message = "<body>THIS IS JUST WAS THE TEST CONTENT</body>";

  destSheet.show(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(message)
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle(NB)
    .setHeight(290)
    .setWidth(765));
}
```

**The Problem is :**  the values of onclick=google.script.run.taxBill(this.**value**) in a third party code won't to called in script of taxBill(this.value) always shown the "**undefined**" it should be the match name has selected in the earlier at the first script of selectCheckBillName. I was trying by another alternative lines to changes the "this.value" line with like this ***"this.taxt()", "this.textContent", "this.data", "this.innerText"*** it seems look like no helpful at all. Please someone chould be can help me. Any achieves will appreciate. Thank you for take your moment to these and apologies for my poor english.

I'd added a pictures to describe more notice for the pic "when the Ellen has choosing tobe click or select and then it must be shown in the red bundaries I've mark for that.
This the failed result of the pic[image]

Comment: Your client-side javascript looks like it would benefit from some cleaning up. Anyway, from what I see there, I think you should be writing `<td OnClick=google.script.run.taxBill(" + val[i] + ")`.

Comment: Yeah, I think that so but I tried this one too but still nothing happened even worsely won't show up the second script of popup at all that's why I didn't write it in my alternative tries.  Any Idea's what's wrong with these why the name has selected won't showup and match with the data table I'd create to connecting to become the data result ???

Comment: `undefined` Where did you log `val`?

Comment: @TheMaster to second function it is taxBill(val) that's the function name to store data to view data result in the client-side of popup.

Comment: @all_master Hy guess I wass added the picture to describbing more my explaination. Check it out! here's the pic :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAx2T.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` property is not present within non-input elements.

Since you already set the inner value to the element, you can change your code to:

`result += "<td OnClick=google.script.run.taxBill(this.innerText)>"+val[i]+"</td>";`

and it will work.

Comment: the output is square no effect still in **"undefined"** outcome.

Comment: @jam Have you republished the app with a **new version** after making the above change?

Comment: my apologies that's my mistake I'd ceate the client script of the third party to hide my main script so the encryption was created by the security to connecting the both of them between the main as server script and the client script so this is what caused it happen.